# AttachConsole has not been declared

Tags: c++, powershell, gcc, wxwidgets

I got the master branch of wxWidget from [here](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets). I downloaded tdm-gcc from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/) (I am certain that mingw32-make which I've used is from inside tdm-gcc). Following the instruction from [wxWiki](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Compiling_wxWidgets_with_MinGW) I executed (many attempts) this on powershell

```
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release clean
mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release
```

But I keep getting the error

```
../../src/msw/app.cpp: In member function 'bool {anonymous}::wxConsoleStderr::DoInit()':
../../src/msw/app.cpp:416:11: error: '::AttachConsole' has not been declared
 if ( !::AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS) )
       ^
makefile.gcc:14269: recipe for target 'gcc_mswu\corelib_app.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [gcc_mswu\corelib_app.o] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Comment: Which version of TDM-GCC do you have? It must be either a very old or a very new one, but I don't know which...

Comment: Try copying `include/wx/msw/setup0.h` to `include/wx/msw/setup.h` and repeat the mingw32-exe commands.

Comment: @VZ. I had used  `tdm64-gcc-5.1.0-2`, using `tdm64-gcc-4.9.2-3` got me rid of that issue at least.

Comment: Very strange, I do see `AttachConsole()` declaration in `x86_64-w64-mingw32\include\wincon.h` distributed as part of TDM-GCC 5.1.0. No idea why the compiler doesn't find it there, could you have corrupted your headers somehow?

Answer (score 3):

Insert

```
#ifndef WINVER
    #define WINVER 0x0603
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_WINNT
    #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0603
#endif

#ifndef _WIN32_IE
    #define _WIN32_IE 0x0700
#endif
```

before

```
#include <_mingw.h>
```

in `include/wx/msw/gccpriv.h`. (This applies [some of this GitHub pull request](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/pull/396) to wxWidgets 3.1.0 as distributed. The next wxWidgets release, whether 3.1.1 or 3.2.0, should resolve this issue.)

Comment: Thank you! this fixed it for me. I'm compiling wx v3.1.0. Strangely, it compiles out of the box with TDM's 64-bit gcc v5.1.0 but failed with this error using MinGW's 32-bit gcc v6.3.0.